# .jpg file not loading in databricks from blob storage (Azure data lake)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have the .jpg pictures in the data lake in my blob storage. I am trying to load the pictures and display them for testing purposes but it seems like they can't be loaded properly. I tried a few solutions but none of them showed the pictures.

```
path = 'abfss://dev@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/username/project_name/test.jpg'

spark.read.format("image").load(path) -- Method 1

display(spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(pic)) -- Method 2
```

Method 1 brought this error. It looks like a binary file (converted from jpg to binary) and that's why I tried solution 2 but that did not load anything either.

```
Out[51]: DataFrame[image: struct<origin:string,height:int,width:int,nChannels:int,mode:int,data:binary>]
```

For method 2, I see this error when I ran it.

```
SecurityException: Your administrator has forbidden Scala UDFs from being run on this cluster
```

I cannot install the libraries very easily. It needs to be reviewed and approved by the administrators first so please suggest something with spark and/or python libraries if possible. Thanks

**Edit:**

I added these 2 lines and it looks like the image has been read but it cannot be loaded for some reason. I am not sure what's going on. The goal is to read it properly and decode the pictures eventually but it cannot happen until the picture is loaded properly.

```
df = spark.read.format("image").load(path)
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending hours on this, I found a solution which was pretty straight forward but drove me crazy. I was on a right path but needed to print the pictures using "binaryFile" format in Spark. Here is what worked for me.

```
## importing libraries
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib. Image as mpimg

## Directory
path_dir = 'abfss://dev@container.dfs.core.windows.net/username/projectname/a.jpg'

## Reading the images
df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(path_dir)

## Selecting the path and content 
df = df.select('path','content')

## Taking out the image
image_list = df.select("content").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

image = mpimg.imread(io.BytesIO(image_list[0]), format='jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
```

It looks like binaryFile is a right format at least in this case and the upper code was able to decode it successfully.

Comment: @saiVamsi thanks for reminding and your help. I appreciate if you can vote it up too.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment, loading dataset into databricks and got below results**:

> **Mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account in Databricks:**

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "xxxxxxxxx", 
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "xxxxxxxxx", 
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token", 
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder_name>", 
mount_point = "/mnt/<folder_name>",
extra_configs = configs)
```

**Or**

> **Mount storage account with databricks  using access key:**

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container>@<Storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/df1/",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.vamblob.blob.core.windows.net":"<access_key>"})
```

[image]

Now, using below code, I got these results.

```
sample_img_dir= "/mnt/df1/"
image_df = spark.read.format("image").load(sample_img_dir)

display(image_df)
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net","<access_key>")
```

[image]

**Reference:**

Mounting [Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6931/mount-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-databricks/) in Databricks By Ron L'Esteve.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Quick question on this and please excuse me for the basic question as I am a newbie in databricks and azure. Does mount storage use DBFS? If yes then we are not allowed to use DBFS.

Comment: hi @hkay, without mounting also you can do, please follow this [link1](https://i.imgur.com/E7zqjsW.png) and [link2](https://i.imgur.com/9MCDA9X.png).

Comment: I tried it before but it gave me this error "Your administrator has forbidden Scala UDFs from being run on this cluster" . when I used link1 or link2

Comment: Please check above update , whether storage account Properly configure or not.

Comment: I tried and it looks the problem is something else. Whenever I run display(df) it throws an error as I mentioned above.